# Complex databinding to DataGridView header text

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Is there a way to complex databind to a column's header text? Or is the only way to manually set the values and listen for change events from the source?

For the record, I've tried both

```
MyDataGrid.DataBindings.Add("Columns[<columnIndex>].HeaderText",MySource,"MyProperty");
```

and

```
MyDataGrid.DataBindings.Add("Columns[\"ColumnName\"].HeaderText",MySource,"MyProperty");
```

to no avail, and neither `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` have a `DataBindings` property.

Comment: What are you binding the DataGridView to? If you bind it to a DataTable, and then change the underlying DataTable's column name, it automatically updates the column on the DataGridView.

Comment: I am binding to a DataTable, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. First off, my headers have spaces, but the problem is the headers will change based on another table. Either way I have to listen to changes and update the text (I can't bind a DataTable column header to something, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the column headers don't support data binding, since it is understood that this metadata will be (largely) static.

In this case, I would simply do it manually, as you propose (read from a property and subscribe to an event to update the column header).

For more complex requirements (for completeness only), you can take more control if you write your own `PropertyDescriptor` implementation, exposed by either `TypeDescriptionProvider` or `ITypedList` - or even better, an `IBindingList` implementation where you raise `ListChanged` events of type `ListChangedType.PropertyDescriptorChanged`; however any of these is a **significant** amount of work, and it simply isn't worth it just for what you are suggesting.